# How to display images from a directory using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image-upload

I need to display images from a directory. Currently, two blank images are displayed first before my images are shown.

I was told to put the condition `if($files>2)`, and it seemed to be working

```
<?php
$dir="imagesbu";
$files=scandir($dir);
if($files)
{
?>
<div class="row">
<?php

foreach($files as $file)
{


?>
<div class="col s6 m3 l3">
<div class="card" style="height:100px; width:150px;">
<div class="card-image">
<img src="imagesbu/<?php echo $file;?>" alt="" style="height:100px; 
width:150px;" >
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php

}
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your file placed and where is your images.show me the path of both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you get the first directories:

- (.) current directory
- (..) parent directory

and then get your files